# How to pass hashmap from activity page to dbhelper class

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to know how could i pass the data from activity page to dbhelper class without intent service.I am getting the data from server and passing the data to the database. i am really confuse.

i have stored data like this way

```
public static HashMap<String, Object> listhashmap;
```

i pass it to dbhelper class, i have used

```
listitems = FirstActivity.arraylistitems;
```

here is the code

```
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DBName, null, version);
            currentContext = context;

            newarraylistitems = FirstActivity.arraylistitems;
            System.out.println("newarraylistitems="+newarraylistitems);

            DBPath = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases";
            createDatabase();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        private void createDatabase() {
            boolean dbExists = checkDbExists();

            /* ("ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE ,
                         "user_message_id" VARCHAR DEFAULT NA, "message" VARCHAR DEFAULT
                         NA, "title" VARCHAR DEFAULT NA, "message_time" VARCHAR DEFAULT NA, "mp3" VARCHAR DEFAULT NA,
                         "userID" VARCHAR DEFAULT NA)*/


            if (dbExists) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                DB = currentContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, 0, null);
    DB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +tableName +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE, " +
            "user_message_id VARCHAR DEFAULT NA," +"message VARCHAR DEFAULT NA," + "title VARCHAR DEFAULT NA)"+
            "mp3 VARCHAR DEFAULT NA "+ "userID VARCHAR DEFAULT NA;");


////some dummy contents
                DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +     
                        tableName +
                        " Values ('M','Sing','India',25);");
                DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                        tableName +
                        " Values ('C','Raje','India',25);");
                DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                        tableName +
                        " Values ('D','Phonu','Argentina',20);");
                DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                        tableName +
                        " Values ('V','Veera','EU',25);");
                DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                        tableName +
                        " Values ('T','Shenoi','Bangla',25);");
                DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                        tableName +
                        " Values ('L','Lamha','Australia',20);");
            }


        }

        private boolean checkDbExists() {
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try {
                String myPath = DBPath + DBName;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {

                // database does't exist yet.

            }

            if (checkDB != null) {

                checkDB.close();

            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

I have already created base adapter for listview ,is there any other way to get the hashmap data of the activity page pass to the dbhelper class 
Here `listitems` is the `hashmap` which i have created in dbhelper class.

can somebody help me @Thanks

Comment: can it be a parameter of your dbhelper method?

Comment: @blackbelt i didn't get you..i need to get the samedata what ever i am getting by server ..could be parameter

Comment: DbHelper/adapter classes usually have static methods where data (as a parameter) can be passed into (to be inserted into the server) from the activity.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @blackbelt can you give any idea ..

Comment: @Zerkz i am using sqlite database where i have created the table i need to insert the value

Comment: @Zerkz Is it possible

Comment: Put the data into sharedprefrence and get the data in other activity easily

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this simple example which implements a SQLiteAdapter in an activity.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite.html

Please note that there are other ways of providing data through a Content Provider (using SQLite), especially when you need to share with other applications. For this, check out Lar Vogel's tutorials (great source, by the way)

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Also, feel free to take a look at some (older, and not the tightest/cleanest code) of an Android project I did a while ago using SQLite.

You can pass the listview items' data over parameters using public methods in your DBhelper/adapter class.

If you want additional help, please post your DBHelper code.

https://github.com/zerkz/Stem-Esteem/blob/master/StemEsteem/src/whipkey/stemesteem/db/StemDbAdapter.java

```
public long createEnding(int weekNo, int stemNo, String ending) {
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(WEEK_NUMBER, weekNo);
values.put(STEM_NUMBER, stemNo);
values.put(ENDING, ending);
return database.insert(TABLE_ENDINGS, null, values);
}

/**
* @updateEnding updates an ending that is already attached to the
* designated stem.
*/

public long updateEnding(int rowid, String ending) {
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ENDING, ending);
return database.update(TABLE_ENDINGS, values, "ROWID" + " = " + rowid,
null);
}

/**
* @deleteEnding deletes an the designated ending attached to a stem.
*/

public boolean deleteEnding(int rowid) {
return database.delete(TABLE_ENDINGS, "ROWID" + " = " + rowid, null) > 0;
}
```

An example of where I call the one of the above methods through an onclick listener in a dialog of an Activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.endingadddialog);

// inflate our views.
inputEnding = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.endingAddInputText);
stem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endingAddStemText);

ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okEndingAddButton);
cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelEndingAddButton);
setTitle("Add Ending");
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // assign the
// function of our
// ok button.
public void onClick(View v) {

StemEsteemApplication.getDbHelper().createEnding(
b.getInt("weekNo"), b.getInt("stemNo"),
inputEnding.getText().toString());
dismiss(); // this will call FillData() through the dismiss
// listener and also kill the dialog.
}
});
```

DISCLAIMER: Please note that there are some things that might be dirty in the above code (like using a global variable (StemEsteemApplication) to get my DbHelper. If someone else better with design patterns would like to correct me, feel free.

Comment: can i add the data continuously it will be auto incremented right

Comment: Please see http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html 

If your tables/schema is implemented with a column that is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, than it should be auto-incremented.

Comment: I cannot answer that unless you post the majority of your DBHelper class code.

Your DBHelper or DBAdapter methods have parameters which you can pass as VALUES for your insert statements into SQLite.

Please take a look at how I have implemented this in some open-source code of mine in the edited version of the answer.

Comment: Zerkz thanks once again ..i have edited the code where i need to insert some values ..i have having hashmap values in other activity..i need to pass only ..kindly help me out

Comment: +1 for your help  i need to pass the values from activity to dbhelper class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30146/discussion-between-zerkz-and-priya2134412)

Comment: If you feel this answer was helpful can you please accept it?